# How to extract separate capitals and numbers from String

Tags: kotlin

I have 2 strings `67 Paris St. Abbeville`  and `344 Paris Main Hgw` and I need to extract separately numbers so Ill have something `var onlyNumbers = "67,344"` and separate capitals like `var capitals = "Paris St. Abbeville,Paris Main Hgw"`

How to filter capitals separate from numbers in those strings?

Comment: Try regex? `findAll("\d+")` and `findAll("[^\d]+")` for example? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/

Comment: Do you have any data where the numbers to be extracted is not the first "word"?

Comment: The example gives much more than just capitals (`PSAPMH`), and more than just letters (`ParisStAbbevilleParisMainHgw`). Do you want to split the digits from _everything_ else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have this

```
val address1 = "67 Paris St. Abbeville"
val address2 = "344 Paris Main Hgw"
```

#### Simple version

If you want a string with only numbers and one without, you can use :

```
val address1Digits = address1.filter(Char::isDigit) // Variant 1
val address2Digits = address2.filter { it.isDigit() } // Variant 2

val address1WithoutDigits = address1.filterNot(Char::isDigit).trim() // Variant 1
val address2WithoutDigits = address2.filterNot { it.isDigit() }.trim() // Variant 2
```

Then you can join the result in a comma-separated string :

```
val address1Digits = address1.filter(Char::isDigit) // Variant 1
val address2Digits = address2.filter { it.isDigit() } // Variant 2

val onlyNumbers = "$address1Digits,$address2Digits"  // "67,344"
val capitals = "$address1WithoutDigits,$address2WithoutDigits"  // "Paris St. Abbeville,Paris Main Hgw"
```

#### "Complex" version

This will do `"123abc456"` -> `"123456"` and `"abc"`
But if what you want an array with all the different numbers (for example `"123abc456"` -> `["123", "456"]`) you can use :

```
val address1Digits = address1.split("\\D+".toRegex()).filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
val address2Digits = address2.split("\\D+".toRegex()).filter { it.isNotEmpty() }

val address1WithoutDigits = address1.split("[^\\D]+".toRegex()).map(String::trim).filter { it.isNotEmpty() }  // Variant 1
val address2WithoutDigits = address1.split("[^\\D]+".toRegex()).map { it.trim() }.filter { it.isNotEmpty() }  // Variant 2
```

Again you can join results

```
val onlyNumbers = (address1Digits+address2Digits).joinToString(",")  // "67,344"
val capitals = (address1WithoutDigits+address2WithoutDigits).joinToString(",")  // "Paris St. Abbeville,Paris Main Hgw"
```

Comment: Tip: If you add code with tests and data from question, it is more likely to get upvotes BR

Comment: Is it better like this ?